# Is it possible that a set of functionally related proteins in a pathway fulfill different functions?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins

Could it be that a given pathway of enzymes (or proteins in general) may fulfill different purposes in a cell by for shifting partners? Say protein A activates B, B activates C and C has a specific action X (e.g. X = phosphorylation of protein D). Now do pathways exist where, e.g., A can activate C directly resulting in action Y (e.g. dephosphorylation of protein D)?

At this time I am in need of real-world examples of this scenario, but I can't find any. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello Costa, and welcome! I don't understand your question. What is supposed to connect to what, what do you mean by property? It's a very broad tem. And maybe you man exhibit, not execute. I know it's not easy if English is not your first language, but people can't answer if they don't know what the question is. You can edit it to add detail, else it's possible that it will be temporarily closed until you explain more.

Comment: Hi Costa Welcome to Stack Exchange! - Thanks for your question! @rumtscho is right. I took a bash at improving your wording a bit, but you may have to elaborate a bit yourself. SE users, and particularly those at Biology SE (myself included :-) can be picky in accepting questions :)

Comment: ps: please feel free to roll my edits back if it is not to your liking

Comment: Just summarizing my current understanding: A -> B -> C effects X. Then, through some mechanism, A -> C effects Y.

Comment: Do you mean C has two X and Y actions and this different actions results from its different stimulator?

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 0):

If Y can be seen as the inverse or absence of X function, it sounds to me like an incoherent type 3 feed-forward loop, where
A activates B
B activates C
A inhibits/reverses C

example from literature, E.coli: fnr as A, and arcA as B, cydAB as C
source: http://www.pnas.org/content/100/21/11980.long

Comment: I3FFLs are quite rare. I haven't really encountered an example of I3FFL. I1FFL is quite common. This you can intuitively guess because A acts as both inhibitor and activator. Though this phenomenon is possible it is not very common.